# Problem with VerifyAction in Moq.FSharp.Extensions

Tags: f#, moq

Trying to create a unit tests for my F# project I have been having trouble.  The closest that I have gotten is by using the Moq.FSharp.Extensions library.  However, I an getting a compile error.

```
let mock = new Mock<IMonitor>()
mock.SetupFunc(fun x -> x.Send(It.IsAny<Alert>())).Returns("OK").End
let obj = mock.Object

let uut = new Scheduler(context, obj, null, null, 10)
let result = uut.Run()

// Assert
mock.VerifyAction((fun x -> x.Send(It.IsAny<Alert>())), Times.Never())
```

I am getting a compile error on the last line.  >>  "This expression was expected to have type 'unit' but here has type string"

I tried wrapping the function that is being complained about like this:

```
mock.VerifyAction((fun x -> (x.Send(It.IsAny<Alert>())) |> ignore),
                                                     Times.Never())
```

When I do that the compile error goes away, but at runtime it complains about having the results of the function being piped to ignore.

Certainly, Moq allows verifying methods that return a value.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that I was using the wrong method...
  When I substituted the mock.VerifyFunc() in place of the mock.VerifyAction() it all worked as I wanted.

```
mock.VerifyFunc((fun x -> x.Send(It.IsAny<Alert>())), Times.Never())
```